# Layout : Inserting text to arrange the views from a controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm building my output using a combination of views. The intention is to arrange the views manually on the page and then fill in the information with the view content i.e. The page arrangement is done by the controller.

Something like this :

```
echo "<html>";
$this -> load -> view('templates/head', $data);
$this -> load -> view('templates/header', $data);
echo "<body>";
$this -> load -> view('templates/navigation', $data);
echo "<main>";
$this -> load -> view('users/view',$data);
echo "</main>";
$this -> load -> view('templates/footer', $data);
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

The problem I'm having is that the tags are clumping together in the output, which is then followed with a dump of the views.  The output is something along the lines of this :

```
<html>
</html>
<body>
<main>
</main>
</body>
... Output From each View ...
```

Has any one had any experience with this kind of thing ? How does one set it up correctly. There is this [site](http://www.williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html) which indicates that templates might be more useful for this purpose. There is also an old [discussion/forum/blog](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Moving-Presentation-Logic-Out-of-Views-with-Code-Igniter/1/), or at least I assume it's old based upon how the classes are instantiated, which shows the assignment of content to the `$data` variable and then finally draws everything in a main view. When I tried the latter, that is collecting the views together before laying them out it did the same.

Is there any way to inject the html into the output ?

(I suspect I missed some mild mannered line in the documentation)

---

The thing I should have searched for was templating, I was under the impression I needed to do this from the controller and thought of it as compositing. From SO the [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266827/creating-a-master-template-in-codeigniter?rq=1), [ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538731/authentication-codeigniter-templates) and [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216519/codeigniter-template-system?rq=1) [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629940/codeigniter-templates?rq=1) answers.

There is no default template mechanism provided by CI, there is a Template Parser Class but that essentially does text replacement in the view. This [site](http://www.reanmachine.com/2011/04/21/codeigniter-theming-a-common-problem/) shows how to generate a view class for those interested.

I initially though there might be a helper function similar to those under the HTML helper class to generate close and open tags, but no dice, hence the question about injection. It seems one may have some control using the Output class.

For those interested : I've gone with a 'layout' folder under views with a set of templates that call the other views. The `<html>/<body>/<main>` tags then wrap around calls to the different sub-views, 'class/view', which I assign to an array in `$data`. The sub-view largest encompassing element is then `<article>`. This keeps the template abstraction to a minimum as far as I can see.

Comment: Why are you producing output in the controller?

Comment: Have a look at CI UserGuide - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html I believe it's very well explained how to use views.

Comment: @Stanyer The idea is not to do so, That's why I asked the question in the first place my code was starting to feel awkward and that's usually a sign that thee is a better way

Comment: @Boris Thanks, I've now read through that and it's some what similar but doesn't detail how to treat composite/nested views, The link by jtheman does a nice job of it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally - the MVC principle should always be the preferred method, then just DON'T use `echo()` statements in the controller. There should be no reason not to put your main structure tags in the view files instead.

HOWEVER

To increase performance Codeigniter views are rendered at the end by default, this is not the case with `echo()` commands that render immediately. Hence all your echoed data will output before the views.

You CAN alter the default behaviour by adding `true` as the third parameter for the views. This will return the view data as a string that then can be echoed:

```
echo $this -> load -> view('templates/head', $data, true);
```

Then it will render in order. I wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: It was feeling bit un MVC-ish. Is there then a standard way for laying out the parts of a page. Is there perhaps a helper/layout/template class ? (I haven't come across it in the Doc's just yet, only started reading/using this system over the weekend)

Comment: Well your question is already un MVC-ish! :) I personally is having the habit of always just loading one view file then in that file load the different view parts I want, like header, footer, menu etc. Just remember to use `$this->load->vars($data);` instead of loading it in the second parameter of the controller so data gets passed through. For an approach on templating, see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/an-introduction-to-views-templating-in-codeigniter/

Comment: That's the best way it seems. Thanks for explaining the output ordering as well. If you're ever in JHB/PTA South Africa I'll buy you a beer :)